# If my javascript array has values that have two elements how can I use one element without the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My alert(arr[0]) equals something like

```
http://server/folder/images/title.png, tagname
```

I want to be able to display the image and use the tagname to sort the order. The build function and json etc is working. I just want to be able access path on it's own and the tag on it's own but still have them related to each other for ordering.

```
 function importJson(str) {

            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            }


            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){

                //alert(xmlhttp.response);


                arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
                for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; var parts = arr[i].split(',');
                     var url = parts[0].trim();
                     var tag = parts[1].trim();
                     alert("h"); index++){

                }

                buildImage(url);

            }





            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://xxxx/~xx/xxxx/content.php");
            xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
            xmlhttp.send();


            function buildImage(imagesrc) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = imagesrc;
                document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
            }
      }
```

Current Code:

```
var arr = [];
var index = 0;

                function importJson(str) {

            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            }


            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {


            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){

               // alert(xmlhttp.response);



                arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
                for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
                    var url = arr[index][0];
                    var tag = arr[index][1];
                    buildImage1(url);

                }


                //buildImage(arr[0]);

            }



            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://cs1.ucc.ie/~mmg6/swipeApp/content.php");
            xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
            xmlhttp.send();


            function buildImage1(imagesrc) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = imagesrc;
                document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Why are you combining the URL and tag in one string, instead of sending an object with them in different elements?

Comment: I thought I'd be able to split up the url and tag. So I could display the image and order array dynamically and easily if they were all combined.

Comment: You can, and my answer will show how, but isn't it more straightforward to send them separately in the first place? The point of using JSON is that you can transmit arbitrary structures, you don't have to do your own parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a 2-dimensional array from your AJAX. So just access the appropriate index of each element of the main array.

```
for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    var url = arr[index][0];
    var tag = arr[index][1];
    buildImage(url);
}
```

Then `buildImage` should take two arguments:

```
function buildImage(imagesrc) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imagesrc;
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/fj9xgjbg/7/)

Comment: Got it working, my current code is working now. Only it displays all the images in the array, I only wanted the first image. And then I could create a function to move through them. Thank you for everything

Comment: If you only want the first image, why do you have a `for` loop? Just use `arr[0][0]`.

Comment: I wanted all the images to be in a array so I could move through them. I'll only be displaying one at a time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60130/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-if-my-javascript-array-has-values-that-have-two-e).